# What is the code convention for formatting try-with-resources?

Tags: java, java-7, indentation, readability, try-with-resources

I'd like to know what the code convention is for formatting try blocks with resources, in particular with more than one resource. Currently I put each resource on its own line, terminated by a semicolon, and use vim's indentation level (2 tab characters), like the following:

```
try (
        InputStream in1 = ...;
        InputStream in2 = ...;
    ) {
    ...;
}
```

I have also seen people use semicolon as a seperator rather than a terminator, and only use a newline between each resource like the following:

```
try (InputStream in1 = ...;
    InputStream in2 = ...) {
    ...;
}
```

What is the convention?

Comment: The convention is whatever your company/organisation tells you it is, usually...

Comment: I don't think the conventions actually go that far, so whatever is consistent with pre-existing code you should do. If you don't have any pre-existing code, just pick what feels better to you.

Comment: But don't forget about readabilty.

Comment: You should be consistent at whichever convention you decide to use. However, if in an isolated use case readability is in conflict with convention , then chose readability.

Comment: Less lines (of code) means more lines (on one screen) - I would go for the second option or even try to put it all on one line if it's not too long. Completely personal obviously...

Comment: consistency > convention

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase it. I am wondering what other people find more readable. Currently I work alone so I can choose whichever convention I want.

Comment: Then refer to first comment. Otherwise, your question is opinion based

Comment: I would definitely increase indentation of `in2` in the second option by one. I don't like it when things almost (but not quite) line up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "right" or "wrong" when aesthetics is involved; and each organization ends up converging on its own coding style. However, it is frequent to borrow coding styles from well-known projects or organizations.

One of the most-used Java code-bases is the JDK itself. After a few greps, I found a multi-line example in OpenJDK 8's `java/lang/Package.java`:

```
/*
 * Returns the Manifest for the specified JAR file name.
 */
private static Manifest loadManifest(String fn) {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fn);
         JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(fis, false))
    {
        return jis.getManifest();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

(there may be other examples within the JDK, but generally speaking, these people are serious about sticking to their guidelines, so I doubt that they will differ).

Comment: The opening curly brace should be on the same line as JarInputStream... See for example [`Files.readAllBytes`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/nio/file/Files.java#Files.readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29)

Comment: Thanks, good points. It seems they separate resource with `;` and a newline, and align them. Finally, they keep the opening bracket on its own line. The latter seems to me a bit unusual.